# Won't Apple reject app?

Tags: ios, app-store

I've got webproject, with two "modes" - first is some kind of drawing, second - showing 3D model in WebGL got from the picture you have drawn.

I want to port it to iOS for some reasons. I've decided not to rewrite first page (it is html page with some js scripts in there), but port WebGL (as I know Apple don't allow it) into some native OpenGL ES code.

Won't Apple reject this app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would they reject it? Unless you are just using a UIWebView and HTML (which you specifically said OpenGL ES, so I assume not), this sounds like a completely legit app.

Comment: I thought that maybe it is not good practice to port things that way, not in "native" way :) thanks, accepting this

Comment: The only thing they don't like is applications simply visiting some website and nothing more. That is what Safari is for. However if your web page is not supported by Safari and you actually make a 3D engine for rendering your content then that is a perfect reason to release an app. It is also allowed to have apps using web views to display content, it is very common.